# Invalid multipolygon of valid individual polygons

Tags: python, shapely

Could anyone please explain this to me? The polygons all have valid geometry but the resulting multipolygon somehow doesn't. The following script:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

polygon1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (1,2), (1,1)])
polygon3 = Polygon([(1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (1,1), (1,0)])
polygon_list = [polygon1,polygon2, polygon3]

mpolygon = MultiPolygon(polygon_list)

for item in polygon_list:
    print(item.is_valid)
for item in mpolygon:
    print(item.is_valid)

print(mpolygon.is_valid)
```

returns the following:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

I believe this is causing me problems as I need to intersect a multilinestring with a multipolygon, and the intersection method requires for all the polygon geometries to be valid.

Why are the individual polygons valid while the full multipolygon is not?

Comment: TL;DR - use `item.buffer(0).is_valid`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `polygon1` and `polygon3` that you created intersect along an infinite amount of points. Taken here from the Shapely documentation:

[image]
*...On the left, a valid MultiPolygon with 2 members, and on the right, a MultiPolygon that is invalid because its members touch at an infinite number of points (along a line)*. [Link](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

To fix this, you need to shift `polygon3` so that it will have a maximum of one intersecting point with the other polygons (or none at all).

Your polygons plotted:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @15Step's answer, If you want to fix the invalidity, use `buffer` method. But if polygons are adjacent, you get `polygon` instead of `multipolygon`.

```
mpolygon = mpolygon.buffer(0)
print(mpolygon.is_valid)
print(type(mpolygon))
# OUT:
#   True
#   <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

[image]

If you need `multipolygon`, you have to convert `polygon` to `multipolygon`.

```
if isinstance(mpolygon, Polygon):
    mpolygon = MultiPolygon([mpolygon])
```

Comment: I need an `mpolygon`, because I wish to do `mpolygon.intersection(multilinestring)` where `mpolygon` has many polygons and `multilinestring` has many LineStrings which may or may not share vertices